# Naming awk output in loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, awk

I'm relatively new to the world of shell scripts so hopefully this won't be too difficult. I have a file (dirlist) with a list of directories. I want to

1. cat 'dirlist' with the path to each file
2. use a program called samtools to modify the file from dirlist
3. use awk to subset the samtools output on a variable chr17
4. write the output to a file that uses the 8th field of the directory, from 'dirlist' for  naming
5. do this for all the files listed in dirlist

I think I have all the pieces here. Items 1-3 are working fine but the loop is simply naming the file "echo".

```
for i in `cat dirlist`; do samtools depth $i | awk '$1 == "chr17" {print $0}'  echo $i | awk -F'[/]' '{print $8}'; done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Instead, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the relevant best practices.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. There are some obvious quoting errors visible even without scrolling to see the full code.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're much better off using awk than bash built-in functionality if you can have just one copy of awk processing *all* your input -- awk is much faster and more efficient than bash when it's running, but like every external process, it takes time to spin up. When you starting running a whole bunch of little processes, things get messy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the suggestions. However, for better or worse, everything in you can see without scrolling works just fine. Simply outputting to a file and naming that output is where the hangup is.

Comment: "Works just fine" depends on your data. Try having a filename containing spaces or glob characters, or changing the value of IFS to something that can exist in your filenames.

Comment: ...the point of suggesting robust practices is to have things that will *always* work, not work as long as your current assumptions continue to be met.

Comment: (The war story I usually trot out here involves multiple TB of billing data backups being lost because someone didn't quote a filename expansion since that name could "only ever" contain hexadecimal characters. Except one day a new program with write access to that directory was using a C module with a buffer overflow, and dumped a bunch of garbage into the filename which happened to contain a whitespace-surrounded `*`. Script tries to delete that one file, script deletes *everything*).

Comment: I understand your aversion to "for" instead of "while". However, why would someone downvote my question? Was there a problem which my actual question? Isn't the reason we come to stackoverflow, to get suggestions like this? Seems petty.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, so I can't speak to it. (I *do* downvote bad questions, rather aggressively -- but when I do so, I'm leaving comments that explain quite explicitly why it's a bad question and how to fix it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't think I was you. Just wondering, in general, what wasn't good about the question in someone's mind. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you want to do

```
... | awk -v f="$i" 'BEGIN{split(f,fs,"/")} $1=="chr17" {print > fs[8]}'
```

the final file name will be generated from the original file name split by "/" and use only the 8th segment.  Kind of unusual, perhaps needs some error handling.

not tested, caveat emptor...

Answer (score 2):

A native bash implementation (just one process, rather than starting an `awk` for every file) follows:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = "chr17"[[:space:]]* ]]; then
      IFS=/ read -r -a pieces <<<"$filename"
      printf '%s\n' "${pieces[7]}"
    fi
  done < <(samtools depth "$filename")
done <dirlist
```

Comment: It does get tiresome correcting the use of a `for` loop to read lines in Bash. Thanks for being so tireless.